# UILabel is not shown in custom UIView screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uilabel

Here is how I implemented my custom UiView

**In myView.h file**

```
@interface myView : UIView
{
    NSString *message;
}
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *messageLabel;
...
@end
```

**In myView.m file**

This function will instantiate myView and add the message label to it

```
+ (id) initWithText:(NSString *) text
{
    screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];

    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, statusBarFrame.size.height, screenBounds.size.width, 40)];

    if (self)
    {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        message = [text copy];
        _messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:[self frame]];
        [_messageLabel setText:message];
        [_messageLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
        [_messageLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
        [_messageLabel setTextColor:[ UIColor blackColor]];
        [self addSubview:_messageLabel];
    }   
   return self;
}
```

Later I add myView as a subclass to the visible view in my screen. When I run the app I can see the red coloured myView but message label is not displayed in it.

Comment: Most likely the label does not have the correct position or size.

Comment: Where do you call initWithText?

Comment: try changing [self frame] to [self bounds] in UILabel initialisation.

Comment: @SuryaSubenthiran I tried `[self bounds]` even then it doesn't display the label. Only red background UiView is visible

Comment: @beyowulf I call the initWithText from another file. I call it using `[[[myView alloc]initWithText:@"My Message"] show];`. The show function will add the view to the window which works as I am able to see myView in screen but only UiLabel is not shown inside it.

Comment: put a breakpoint and po the label frame, and see if it is out of screen or not

Answer (score 2):

When you init your UILabel with self.frame, you have to consider the value inside its parent view.

Maybe your 2nd parameter: y = statusBarFrame.size.height is to high and that's why your label is out your view ?

Try to init your label with CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.width, self.frame.height)

Comment: In the beginning I was using `CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.width, self.frame.height)` but then I thought bounds are getting exceeded so I replaced it to `[self frame];`. When `[self frame]` is called it returns the X and Y origin of itself so I thought it then won't exceed the bounds. Both these method didn't show the UiLabel.

Answer (score 1):

check if text you are setting in label is blank and

```
_messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame];
```

Comment: I checked in runtime too. Label is not set to blank. message is NSString and it contains the string properly. and I tried self.frame too but it doesn't display the label.

Comment: try hardcoding both     _messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];_messageLabel.text = @"asd";

Comment: I tried but it doesn't show. I tried changing text colours too but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried this code And it worked. Sure that you didn't set other parameters to your UILabel somewhere else ? These are the differences with your code :

- I replaced your '+' by '-' for the method.
- I changed uilabel frame for initialisation.
- Added a background color to label (only to check).

  ```
  -(id)initWithText:(NSString *)text
  {
  CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
  CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];

  self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, statusBarFrame.size.height, screenBounds.size.width, 40)];

  if (self) {
  [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

  NSString *message = [text copy];
  UILabel *_messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
  [_messageLabel setText:message];
  [_messageLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightTextColor]];
  [_messageLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
  [_messageLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
  [_messageLabel setTextColor:[ UIColor blackColor]];
  [self addSubview:_messageLabel];
  }
  return self;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**Before:**  I used to call `initWithText()` & `show()` from `backgroundOP.m` file where I do background operations. These functions are always executed in separate threads.

**Now:** I moved the call to `initWithText()` & `show()` method inside a delegate method and added the delegate to presenting UIViewController i.e., inside the viewController.m file in which I want my view to appear. Now I call this delegate from another file (i.e., from `backgroundOP.m`) and problem is solved. Now both `UIView` and `UILabel` is visible in screen.

But I don't understand why adding the UIView from the background thread function shows only the UIView and not its contents/subviews.

In my show() function, I use this dispatch queue to add the myView to presenting key window. Like below code

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[window addSubview:self]; // self represents myView object
 });
```

**If someones knows the reason for this behaviour, please enlighten me.**